# Не работает js как надо в html, а также еще WP

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Я это выполняю заказчику, если кто-то успею помочь до 21, то отдам 50% (250 рублей).

Я редактирую уже готовый шаблон для WP, хочу добавить туда меню с выпадающим списком. Вроде все выполнил, но тут одна проблемка, чтобы было нормально понятно, вот сразу код:

```html
<ul id="menu">
<li><span><a href="#">ВЫЕЗДНАЯ РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</a></span>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">- РЕГИСТРАТОРЫ</a></li>
<li><a href="#">- ОФОРМЛЕНИЕ</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Дело в том, что меню работает с привлечением JS, и для того чтобы оно выпадало, надо вот этот `span`, потому что когда я его убираю, оно никак не работает (пробовал уже создать класс для `li` и прочее, не работает все равно).
Я знаю, в WP есть классы для `li`, но как я уже писал выше, если делать через эти классы, никак не срабатывает JS.

Так вот, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы меню работало без этого `span`, чтобы я мог его спокойно использовать на WP, например вот так:

```html
<li class="span_li"><a href="#">ВЫЕЗДНАЯ РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</a>
```

Или как мне этот span добавить в WP?

Вот веб-сайт на WP: http://wyksa.cardnew.sv-one.ru
И вот меню, которое я пытаюсь туда вставить: http://siivex.com/test/menu

Comment: Ну самое простое это отредактировать скрипт, и настроить его без спана, но можно еще и расширить класс `walker_nav_menu`, он отвечает за формирование и вывод меню в WP.  С помощью этого класса можно сформировать `html` код меню как угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете отредактировать html разметку в вашем активном шаблоне и добавить (убрать) всё что мешает. Но по сути ваш скрипт очень прост и его можно написать самостоятельно под вашу разметку. С jquery что-то вроде:

```
$('#menu > li').click(function(event) { $(this).toggleClass('shown') })
```

и соответствующий css для вложенных меню:

```
#menu li > ul {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

#menu li.shown > ul > li {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```